# Stopping Push Notifications sent to Apple for delivery

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, push-notification

Again same question title but requirement is somewhat different.

We have implemented push notification in our application. For some reason there is some problem and lots of push notifications sent to all the participant of our application.

Is there any way to delete notifications sent to apple for delivery ? i.e. messages already send to apple server for delivery of notification.

Sounds weird but need help if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As soon as the message is transmitted to Apple, you lose control of it. There are no APIs to cancel a delivery.

For the record: I've built a system we use internally that works as a proxy to Apple's servers. If a message is queued there, we can cancel delivery. But this is completely custom, and the message hasn't actually been delivered to Apple yet.